# Cannot perform sendkeys with value {Enter} on control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to use the `CodedUI` Test feature of `Visual Studio 2010.`

**What I do is:**

- I enter a value to textbox,
- then press Enter
- and this should lead to a `pop-up message`(messagebox should say it's
  wrong value, press Ok button to continue).

When I play recorded test it throws an **exception**

> PlayBackFailure exception was unhandled by user code
>   TechnologyName:  "MSAA"
>   Name:  "Menge/ArtNr/Ls"
>   ControlType:  "Edit"

and indicates to the code shown below

```
{Keyboard.SendKeys(uIScannBoxEdit, this.PressEnterParams.UIScannBoxEditSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);}
```

**I tried**

```
{Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
    Keyboard.SendKeys(uIScannBoxEdit, this.PressEnterParams.UIScannBoxEditSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
}
```

but didn't really help.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I would wrap the offending code in a try-catch and examine the exception more closely in debug.

Comment: what do you mean? Could you please give more detailed explanation?

Comment: @DonBoitnott: Thanks, put keyboard.sendkeys in try catch, solved problem.